# request statuscode getting 404 but working in postman - node

Tags: node.js, express

I am trying to hit an API from node using request. It is giving statusCode as 404 but working in postman surprisingly

```js
var options = {
  method: 'POST',
  url: 'https://soandsourl.com,
  headers:   { 
    'cache-control': 'no-cache',
    'Connection': 'keep-alive',                   
    'Host': 'soandsourl.com',                   
    'Cache-Control': 'no-cache',
    'Accept': '*/*',
    'User-Agent': 'PostmanRuntime/7.17.1',
    'Content-Type': 'application/json'
  },
  body: reqParams,
  json: true
};

request(options, function (error, response, body) {
  console.log(error, "error++++");
  // console.log(response, "response++++");
  console.log('statusCode:', response && response.statusCode);
});
```

Can you guys please help, What is missing here?

Comment: did you match the url in code and the one in postman is same?

Answer (score 0):

Postman by itself adds some headers (temporary) most of which are not necessary from your server. Assuming you are using the snippet you mentioned in your APIs request options, please remove extra headers and try again.